# How to delete vagrant snapshots

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have ended up having 2 snapshots with same name for a VM in a vagrant multi machine setup. I thought saving again with same name would overrride. Now I want to delete one of them but when I give the name I get

```
➜  vagrant vagrant snapshot list trusty                  
my-pkg_1.0
my-pkg_1.0

➜  vagrant vagrant snapshot delete trusty  'my-pkg_1.0'
Progress: 0%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["snapshot", "11ea7bf9-717c-453d-91e3-4185cec6be92", "delete", "my-pkg_1.0"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Snapshot 'my-pkg_1.0' of the machine 'vagrant_trusty_1482140927350_10789' cannot be deleted, because it is the current snapshot and has one child snapshot
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "DeleteSnapshot(bstrSnapGuid.raw(), pProgress.asOutParam())" at line 421 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
```

Comment: Use the Virtualbox GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete directly from vboxmanage CLI by running

```
$ vboxmanage list vms --> this list all your VM with name and UUID
$ vboxmanage snapshot <virtualbox_vm_name> list --> this list the snapshot with vbox name and snapshot UUID
$ vboxmanage snapshot <virtualbox_vm_name> delete <snapshot_UUID_from_previous_command>
```